# Definir MONGO_URL em um projeto Meteor dentro do arquivo settings.json

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Estou começando a trabalhar com o [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com) e estou tendo muita dificuldade com algo que deveria ser simples: mudar a string de conexão com um mongodb próprio. Já busquei pela internet, também pelo próprio stackoverflow [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824944/unable-to-set-mongodb-path-in-meteor-on-window-system), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588038/how-do-i-use-the-existing-mongodb-in-a-meteor-project) e em outros links diferentes mas nenhum deles me da uma solução que seja "politicamente correta".

Pelo que eu vi na documentação do Meteor, eu tenho como trabalhar com um arquivo `settings.json` onde o mesmo deveria me deixar definir a variável **MONGO_URL** manualmente assim.

```
{
  "env":{
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb"
  }
}
```

O problema é que não sei como forçar o meteor a executar ele sempre, sem que seja necessário definir na linha de comando a função `--settings` porque se eu gerar uma aplicação em ambiente de produção, não vejo o --settings como funcional, na verdade eu preciso que o Meteor não crie uma base de dados e retorne um erro quando não encontrar o banco.

**EDIT:**
Consegui fazer com que conectasse em uma base própria quando eu criei um BAT com os comandos abaixo:

```
SET MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb
meteor
```

Mas não concordo que seja essa a única maneira de fazer com que o Meteor acesse outra base, além disso ele não irá me retornar um erro caso não encontre a base, ao contrário, se não encontrar ele irá criar a sua própria base.

Answer (score 0):

O Meteor permite que você crie comandos personalizados no arquivo `package.json`. Por exemplo, crie no arquivo `package.json` o seguinte:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/yourdb meteor run"
  }
}
```

Depois, basta você executar o seguinte comando:

```
$ meteor npm run start
```

O ideal é que você deixe o MONGO_URL do arquivo settings.json para o banco de produção.